# How to hide UIButton if Reward Ad is not loaded in Swift?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, uibutton, admob, ads

I am currently incorporating ads into my game on `spritekit` and I have a button where if clicked the user can get free coins for watching an ad. However this only runs once the ad is loaded, the issue is the button is still there. I want the button to be hidden whilst the ad is not loaded yet and appear once the ad is loaded. I removed irrelevant code from my view controller.

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class GameViewController: UIViewController, GADBannerViewDelegate, GADRewardBasedVideoAdDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var bannerView: GADBannerView!

   @IBOutlet weak var playRewardAd: UIButton!

        override func viewDidLoad() {

            super.viewDidLoad()

            GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().load(GADRequest(),
                                                    withAdUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313")

            GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().delegate = self

            bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
            bannerView.rootViewController = self
            bannerView.load(GADRequest())

    @IBAction func playVideoAd(_ sender: Any) {

        if GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().isReady == true         {
            GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().present(fromRootViewController: self)
        }        
}

    func rewardBasedVideoAdDidClose(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd) {
        GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().load(GADRequest(),
                                                withAdUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313")

    }

    func rewardBasedVideoAd(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd,
                            didRewardUserWith reward: GADAdReward) {
        coinNumber = coinNumber + 100
        defaults.set(coinNumber, forKey: "coinsSaved")
        coinLabel.text = "\(coinNumber)"
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/ios/api/reference/Protocols/GADRewardBasedVideoAdDelegate#/c:objc(pl)GADRewardBasedVideoAdDelegate(im)rewardBasedVideoAdDidReceiveAd: `-rewardBasedVideoAdDidReceiveAd:` may help you. Hide the button in `viewDidLoad` , and show the button in `-rewardBasedVideoAdDidReceiveAd:`

Comment: hello thank you that worked, however this only works the first time the ad is used. After the ad is closed for the first time, it starts to load again however is still visible.

Comment: just fixed it by hiding the button again after the ad closes. Thank you this was all thanks to you.

Comment: How about setting `playRewardAd.isHidden = true` in `rewardBasedVideoAdDidClose` and/or `rewardBasedVideoAd`

Comment: Could you help me remove the button from other scenes? It interferes with scenes such as the gamescene etc. I only want it to be within the main menu scene  and game over scene

Comment: Are you meaning `playRewardAd` should always be hidden in gameschene, and should be shown only in main menu or game over scene? Adding check the current scene before showing the button, and show the button if the current scene is not gamescene and Ad is ready may work, but I don't understand your problem maybe...

Comment: I have four scenes; MainMenu, Game, Store and GameOver. I only want the button to be shown in Main Menu and GameOver and to be hidden in Game and Store.

Comment: Maybe the method above conflicts with this as The button will ALWAYS now show once the ad is loaded regardless of the scene.